# Multi-Stage Spring Boot Dockerization Using Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, docker, dockerfile

Trying to get the multi-stage Spring Boot application Dockerfile that works.

The idea is to:

1. Build and package the project using `mvn package` command
2. Run the built .jar file

After some research, I found *[this](https://dzone.com/articles/build-package-and-run-spring-boot-apps-with-docker)* article. It provides complete Dockerfile, but it does not work for me.

I modified the initial Dockerfile, and now it looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-8-slim AS MAVEN_BUILD

COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/

RUN mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -Ptest # This line does not work properly

FROM openjdk:8-jre

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/platform-0.0.1.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "platform-0.0.1.jar"]
```

I created a `docker-compose.yml` that tries to build this Dockerfile:

```
[...]
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    ports: 
      - "8080:8085"
[...]
```

After running the `docker-compose up --build -d` command, I always get this error:
[image: docker-compose log]

Am I missing something?

Running the `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -Ptest` command in the actual project folder works normally...

Comment: Try some basic operation on/with the executable maven file. E.g. try to tail/head it, execute a basic mvn command e.g. mvn -version, list the content of the /usr/bin/ directory. Are the permissions are correct? Does the file exist? Maybe try another builder image (substitute maven:3.6.2-jdk-8-slim)

Comment: @Urasche Great suggestion. Although I already tried the `mvn -version`, the same result, I will check the permissions & contents of `/usr/bin/` and update the post with info

Comment: Ok, after showing the contents of /usr/bin, I got this error: `/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied` and after that this one: `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: How you tried showing the content of the /usr/bin? What was the exact command? Maybe try to run the container as a root/system admin. Gain root access on the host machine and execute the command: docker-compose up --build -d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my docker client installation. It somehow did not setup necessary permissions after installation. On other machines, this Dockerfile works fine.

Well, this was a lesson for some future times.